# Google App Engine - Console Output

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I am running a Java Microengine on GAE.

I have my own html pages for data input and output.  When there is a data error and the engine cannot complete its execution (crashes) - the microengine spits out the "Response" as Server not available, please try later.

In order to debug, I run the dataset in the dev environment - as a Java application to identify the error in the console output.

Is there a way to capture the "error" (the console output equivalent when run as a Java application) - as an output string and send it as a content of the servlet response from the deployed Application in GAE..

thanks,

Comment: Wrap something like `try{ . . . }catch(Exception e){Output e.toString() as response}` around the code that crashes?

Comment: Thanks @konki.  I have added the try catch an also sending the result in json output.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using App Engine Managed VM, and a logging framework, you should also forward the log entry into a file, e.g. /var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/app.log

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/custom-runtimes#logging

Subsequently, you'll be able to read the output from Google Cloud Logging.

Comment: Thanks @saturnism.  I have activated the logging and it helped significantly.